# Const struct initialization with custom elements in C++

Tags: c++, struct, designated-initializer

I am porting some C code to C++ and I am trying to initialize a struct with some values.
I want the struct to be stored in flash (const) and not in RAM, and its values are typedef'd elements.

Originally, I had it like this:

```c
typedef struct
{
    typeA_t elementA;
    typeB_t elementB;
    uint8_t elementC;
} structTypeA_t;
```

And to instantiate them in flash, I simply did the following:

```c
const structTypeA_t sA = {
    .elementA = ONE,
    .elementB = TWO,
    .elementC = 3
};
```

I know that this type of initializing is not allowed in C++. How can I achieve it in C++?

Comment: It's allowed in C++20 (with some restrictions). Do you need a solution for older standard versions?

Answer (score 3):

Designated initializers are not in C++ (yet, but look for C++20). So you do it almost the same way, but without names - position of the argument defines the field it initializes:

```
const structTypeA_t sA = {ONE,
                          TWO,
                          3
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always need to initialize with the same values, then you can just define the struct like this:

```
struct structTypeA_t
{
    typeA_t elementA = ONE;
    typeB_t elementB = TWO;
    uint8_t elementC = 3;
};
```

You can now instantiate it without an initializer:

```
const structTypeA_t sA;
```